# What happens with seized money?

Tags: search-and-seizure, switzerland, money-laundering

Daniel the drug dealer was caught with 20.000€ of illegaly earned money while crossing the border into Switzerland. The money was covered in traces of all kinds of drugs, so the court did not believe any of his stories about where he got the money from (also, cash in excess of 10.000€ must be declared when crossing the border, as a measure against tax evasion). The court found him guilty of drug dealing, attempted money laundering and similar crimes and charged him with a fine of 1000Fr, plus court fees.

But what happens with the seized money? I can think of several options:

- It is returned to Daniel, deduced by the fine. (Unlikely, because in this case, the crime would have been worth it, as the fine is significantly lower than the cash earned)
- The money is destroyed by the court (Destroying money is illegal in itself, though)
- The money becomes property of the state (Sounds a bit weird, as this would make the state benefit from a crime)

Comment: I'm seeing two problems with the assertions you make setting up your question: 1) Why do you think 'destroying money' is illegal? As far as I'm aware it's only a crime for private citizens to deface or destroy legal tender, which is an entirely different thing from the court, as an agent of government, declaring the money forfeit.

Comment: ... And 2) this does not make the state benefit from a crime. At its most cynical reading, this would make the state benefit from *catching a criminal*. All other considerations aside for the sake of this particular discussion, apprehending criminals sounds like behavior that should be incentivized.

Comment: @Shadur These are probably just the points I'm missing. I'm asking because all of the possibilities I can imagine have some question mark behind them.

Comment: FWIW, almost all currency in circulation has traces of drugs on it. Currency used by drug dealers doesn't have more than currency used by other people. Of course, we can assume otherwise for purposes of the hypothetical in the question, since that is really only a nitpicky side point.

Comment: Switzerland would not be interested in the EU **exit** requirements for cash. [Cash, foreign currencies, securities - Federal Office for Customs and Border Security FOCBS - Switzerland](https://www.bazg.admin.ch/bazg/en/home/information-individuals/bans--restrictions-and-authorisations/cash--foreign-currencies--securities.html): *Unrestricted amounts of liquid funds, i.e. cash, foreign currency and securities (shares, bonds and cheques) can be imported into Switzerland, brought through Switzerland in transit or exported from Switzerland. Furthermore, the funds **do not need to be declared**.*

Comment: @MarkJohnson Interesting find. However, the following paragraphs kind of conflict with that statement. Apparently, you can bring a lot of cash, but you still need to declare where you got it from upon request. And maybe there's some kind of agreement between the states which allows the Swiss customs to also control EU exit regulations (or the news report I got the story from was oversimplified).

Comment: Doubtfull that the Swiss banks would like the idea of the enforcement of EU exit regulations on cash.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Very likely true from the management's perspective, but not from the perspective of finance regulations. In the last decade, regulations on banks have been extremely tightened and most banks have understood that they risk severe fines when not conforming to international standards. The days when you could easily hide your illegally gained money (or money from tax evasion) on Swiss accounts with no questions asked are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The money is forfeited to the state

This would normally be the case even if Daniel is acquitted. The proceeds of crime may be seized using forfeiture rules which require Daniel to prove that the suspect money is legitimate.

Comment: Something to back this up would be nice.